# Help updating question

Tags: discussion, suggested-edits

I've been reading a lot at meta about how to make SO a better place. I had posted an answer at [Asterisk inbound/outbound SIP trunk with Twilio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18883751/asterisk-inbound-outbound-sip-trunk-with-twilio/19570171#19570171) with only two links to my blog. Read here why that's discouraged and then wrote a complete response with two links at the bottom.

You can see that the person who did the question isn't really well versed on Asterisk, but it's a valid question (and one that I had when started playing with it). I arrived to that question on google and then replied it when I found a solution for myself.

The problem with the question is that it includes his configuration file... but it's completely messed up and it doesn't really add to the question. So, I [edited it](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/3304861), completely removing the configuration file (and adding that make and receive calls which can be inferred from that configuration attempt). But [the edit](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/3304861) got rejected... is there anything wrong with my edit? what would make more sense?

Thanks!

Comment: Problem is - only OP can reliably narrow the too broad question down. If anyone else will try, chance is that parts important to the OP will get deleted, and unimportant left to be the new question.

Comment: Given that the question you wanted to answer is a fair bit different than the one that was asked, even if they are similar, it would probably be best for you to simply ask your own question an answer it.  Self answered questions *are* hard, you should make sure to write the question as if you aren't going to answer it, and answer it as if you didn't write it.  Write the question as you would have before you found the answer.  That will allow you to decouple the question from the one asked, which is 1) not a particularly great question, 2) not from an active user.

Comment: I'm answering his question though... Actually, my bad... The question is not broad at all, he's asking something concrete, how to make and receive calls from/to twilio... I'd be just deleting non relevant configuration attempts. Considering that the configuration he posted doesn't even meet Asterisk format of configuration files, doesn't removing it make sense?

Comment: It's not different... A trunk lets you make and receive calls, and he wants to use twilio as a trunk, which is what I'm answering. Btw, I just want to answer it b/c after I put my links there, I got lots of visits with people who found my posts useful... The question appears 2nd on google when searching for twilio asterisk calls

Comment: Ok... so I guess I'll make a new question and just reply it with my answer... the problem is that I'd just ask the same thing, that is "How can I use Twilio as an Asterisk trunk to send and receive calls?". Does it really add value? It would have value for me (I'd get the rep from people who upvote my question and my answer) but not sure if it would add to the community

Comment: @GervasioMarchand Such a question would be a very low quality question, for the same reason that the existing question is of low quality.  It's too broad, doesn't specify what the author has really tried, etc.  The question itself should narrow the scope of the answers, indicate research and effort in solving the problem, etc.

Comment: Sorry to bother again... I think I'm going to give it a try to my question. Does this question make sense? `I have a Twilio account which has a number (let's say 8881231234), and I have Asterisk box. I'd like to use Twilio as an Asterisk trunk to be able to make calls at their rates and receive calls from that number on my Asterisk.

I haven't found any specs to interconnect Asterisk with Twilio. Is it possible to set up Asterisk so that every outgoing call is routed through Twilio and have the calls on my 8881231234 number ring on my SIP phone?`